# How to make an AWS EC2 instance accessible only via a private IP address?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I have a database running on AWS EC2 and I want it to NOT be accessible via any public IPs or DNS. I only want it to be accessible via a private IP address, so that a Node.JS within the same AWS zone could connect to it via an internal IP address (not a public one). So something like `localhost` but an AWS version of it.

Is this at all possible? How to do that? I didn't find anything online about it.

Comment: Please read about VPC components. Then, explore a little bit about security group. You will get your answer. Good luck.

Comment: @HasmukhRathod this is such a great advice. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking an instance is private as long as a
[public IPv4 address is not assigned](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-ip-addressing.html#vpc-public-ip).

Instances with public IPv4 addresses but no Internet Gateway attached as a route will not allow inbound traffic as long as an internet gateway is not attached, **although** this should not be used to make an instance private as it is easy to be reversed.

The best approach is to create private subnets for where the private instances should exist, ensure that the setting for [auto assign public IPv4 is not enabled](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-ip-addressing.html#subnet-public-ip).

Create a separate route table for the subnets and if you want the instances to be able to connect to the internet create either a Nat gateway or Nat instance for IPv4 traffic and add a route to the internet in your route table to use these as the target.

If you want ipv6 traffic outbound too you will need perform the above with an egress only gateway.

Check out [this AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Scenario2.html) for a further breakdown of public and private network configuration.

Comment: I think it's more accurate to say that an instance is private as long as it doesn't have a route to IGW.

Comment: Thanks @jellycsc, this is also true I have updated my answer to include this, although with a caveat that its very easy to make an instance with a public IP publicly accessible again. With no public IP ever attached it can never be public regardless of routing :)